# How to use onclick button to request php api

Tags: php

```
$response = Unirest\Request::get("https://cometari-airportsfinder-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/airports/by-radius?radius=50&lng=-157.895277&lat=21.265600",
  array(
    "X-RapidAPI-Host" => "cometari-airportsfinder-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key" => "xxxx"
  )
);
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Comment: Thank you Robert Columbia for the respond. In the future I will make sure the question does show a research effort. API is new to me. Moreover, many professionals out in the world have the heart and the integrity to teach others. So, then it becomes an extraordinary experience.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and will display the result in a div.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="$.get('/ajax-rapidapi.php', function(result) { $('#result').html(result); });">Click Me!</button>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP (ajax-rapidapi.php)**

```
<?php

die(Unirest\Request::get("https://cometari-airportsfinder-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/airports/by-radius?radius=50&lng=-157.895277&lat=21.265600", array( "X-RapidAPI-Host" => "cometari-airportsfinder-v1.p.rapidapi.com", "X-RapidAPI-Key" => "02f2e99835msh60df6f30e23585dp137d84jsn437639993023")));
```